# Resizeable and pinch to zoom plugin

Tags: javascript, resize, touch

I'm looking for a JS plugin that does something identical to [jQuery UI Resizeable](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/) but works on pinch-to-zoom on touch devices.

What would be the simplest way to implement that functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You should check [hammer.js](http://hammerjs.github.io/) out.

The documentation is also very clear so you should be ok.